# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ]

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, shared-hosting

I got this error as soon as I tried to run the nodejs app in Godaddy shared hosting cPanel terminal while trying to connect to mongo atlas cluster.

[image: Error]

I have whitelisted both the IP of the server and set access to all still not working.

Same code is working fine in local system
[image]

My node.js code goes as:
[image]

Here is the DB url
[image]

If anyone has experienced this issue and able to solve it, then please provide me the solution. Thanks :) in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read this first, before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And also, please format you code and insert images correctly. With special (triple `) markdown tags and `post an image` button, not via url links

Comment: Are you using MongoDB Compass? If so, can you connect to your database with the current `connection` link?

Comment: And **YES**, according to your console, the problem is with the IP whitelisting, probably you don't know show network working and have get IP.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure, that you IP is a provider's IP, not you own. According to a console, problem is in whitelisting.

So make sure that you are enable in your driver, all connections options, like this:
(*if you are using mongoose*)

```
connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.login}:${process.env.password}@${process.env.hostname}/${process.env.auth_db}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    w: "majority",
    family: 4
});
```

And then white-list every IP in your Atlas console, like that:

[image]